WinUI 3 ListView (or ScrollView) inside a ScrollView
I search a solution to use a listview inside a Scrollview, without success at a time 
The result I want is like a web page, in xaml you have a Page with a Scrollview and for child a grid and inside this grid some controls.
One of this controls is a ListView with for layout properties a dedicated row (*) and a minimum height (600).
If the window is to small to give the minimum height the page scrollview enter in action, and when the window is bigger than required the page scrollview is unactive and the builtin scrollview of listview enter in action (if the item list requiered more than available height) and the listview take the available height (row with *) to fill the viewport.
In the exemple below, when I use a control without a builtin scrollview instead of ListView this work like a charm. But with a control with a builtin scrollview, no. The listview take the height required for all items and never use the builtin scrollview and don't respect the * of the row, uh no, this is not exactly true..
Why when a control without builtin ScrollView is inside a ScrollView the * is by the viewport of host Scrollview and when a control with builtin ScrollView is in the same case the * it's infinite ?
<Page>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Stackoverflowwwwwww" />
            
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" 
                      MinHeight="600" />
        </Grid>
    <ScrollView>
<Page>

I don't understand why the behavior is different with a control with builtin scrollview or without a builtin scrollview.
Microsoft ListView MAUI
Microsoft warning on scroll in scroll
EDIT
This is reproductible standalone code
<Window
x:Class="EraseMe.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:EraseMe"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem Header="Grid in *">
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="Stackoverflowwwww" />

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                          MinHeight="600"
                          Background="Red" />
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
            
            <PivotItem Header="ListView in *">
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="Stackoverflowwwww" />

                    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                              MinHeight="600">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="200" 
                                      Margin="10"
                                      Background="Blue"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Items>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                        </ListView.Items>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>

Get this picture :
The host scrollview is used and not the scrollview of listview
The height constraint with * have not the same behavior, with a control with builtin scrollview or without

I don't understand what exactly is your issue. Can you post a reproducible sample code?

Thank for your comment @AndrewKeepCoding, I've added a reproductible code.
The issue is why when I use inside a ScrollView an another control with builtin scrollview the controls doesn't respect the same philosophie with the *.
In case of grid or any other control without builtin scrollview the control is stretch to fill the viewport when the height available from viewport is bigger than 600 otherwise the scrollview is here to maintain the min height for this control to 600.
With a control with builtin scrollview,  it takes all the height necessary for its content!

This is because the ScrollView will make its contents stretch to the size they require.
In this case, the ListView will have the height to show its 9 items without its own ScrollBar.
If you set the ListView's Height to, let's say 700, the ListView will keep that height and will use its own ScrollBar.
UPDATE
The following code works:
private ContentControl? PivotControlHeaderClipper { get; set; }

private void RootScrollView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshSize();
}

private void PivotControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PivotControlHeaderClipper = (sender as Pivot)?.FindDescendant<ContentControl>(x => x.Name is "HeaderClipper");
    RefreshSize();
}

private void RefreshSize()
{
    double listViewHeight = RootScrollView.ActualHeight;
    listViewHeight -= PivotControlHeaderClipper?.ActualHeight ?? 0;
    listViewHeight -= PivotItemRootGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight;

    if (listViewHeight > 0 &&
        ListViewControl.Height != listViewHeight)
    {
        ListViewControl.Height = listViewHeight;
    }
}

Notes:

Name the ScrollView "RootScrollView".
Name the Grid inside the PivotItem "PivotItemRootGrid".
The "PivotControlHeaderClipper" is a part of the Pivot control. You can see how is impemented in the generic.xaml file.
FindDescendant comes from the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions NuGet package.


Yes ! This is exactly that. If I set a Height or MaxHeight the control doesn't use more than set height. BUT it's terribly ugly ! Scrollbar in Scrollbar for maybe 10px when the viewport of host scrollview can't give the required height or an empty space between the bottom of listview & the bottom of window.
Set a Height or MaxHeight is (for me) definitely not clean ! In this case, you doesn't fill the viewport of host dynamically OR you fill it to mutch (imagine with 1 000 items).
In fact, it's possible to define the priority to the scrollview of control instead of host scrollview ?

Updated my answer. Hope it helps.
